# Совместить объекты на разных Canvas Unity UI

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два разных канваса, и нужно чтобы объект на одном был точно поверх объекта на другом.

Банальное `object1.transform.position = object2.transform.position` не работает, `object1` улетает в нулевые координаты.

`object1.anchoredPosition = object2.anchoredPosition` тоже не работает, так как у них разные привязки.

Есть ли какой нибудь способ абсолютного позиционирования этих элементов, чтобы точно можно было наложить один на другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перевести координаты одного из объектов в screen point(от 0:0 до ширина:высота экрана) с помощью [Camera.WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html). После чего эти координаты можно будет перевести в локальные координаты относительно другого RectTransform с помощью [RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html)